# display 4 columns next to each other and among each other when resizing

Tags: html, css

i have the following issue:
i am trying to display 4 Columns in 1 row of information next to each other.
now, this works fine, but when i resize the page, the columns are not breaking to display on a new row. so how would i change it to make it possible for the columns to display among one another ?
thanks in advance.

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
  border-spacing: 20px;
}
.Column {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">
    TEST 1
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    TEST 2
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    TEST 3
  </div>

  <div class="Column">
    TEST 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i suggest you read more on the bootstrap site.

Comment: hi... i am using this as a auction template on eBay.. Bootstrap is not supported on eBay... and also, do you really think it is so complicated to use bootstrap for it ?

Comment: i see... and true, if you float the column left... it will drop below when the content is to long. if you play around with float:left on divs.. im sure you will work it out from there.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/9deLmbps/3/

Comment: @lahori: thank you...interesting to see a solution using bootstrap, but still iam not allowed to use external scripts ..but good solution

Comment: @lebhero I didn't use bootstrap. Its plain css. I updated the [link ][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/9deLmbps/7/  by removing bootstrap link that is causing confusion and BTW sorry for late reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So tables are not the way to go when thinking responsive. using floats or media queries would be the way to tackle it. check out tutorials for the box model.

```
.Row {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 20px;
}
.Column {
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 100px;
}
```

play with padding and margins to place them where you want